Does $f$ attain its minimum?

Let $C[0,1]$ be a family of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ with the
norm $$\|x\|_{\infty}=\max\limits_{t\in [0,1]}|x(t)|.$$Define $$A=\{x\in
 C[0,1]; \|x\|_{\infty}\leq 1, x(1)=1\}.$$
a) Let $f: C[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}, x\mapsto\min\limits_{t\in[0,1]}x(t).$ Is $f$
continuous on $A$?
b) Does $f$ attain its minimum on $A$? Is $A$ compact?

I already done part a) with the answer that $f$ is continuous on $A$, in fact uniformly continuous. I also proved $A$ is not compact by considering the sequence $f_n(x)=x^n\subset A$. This sequence contains no convergent subsequence, so $A$ is not compact. I'm stuck at the question:"Does $f$ attain its minimum on $A$"?
I would be very appreciated if someone could help me with last part of this problem? Thanks in advance!

$x(t) \ge -1$ for all $x \in A$ so $f(x) \geq -1$ on $A$. Define $x(t)=2t-1$. Then $x \in A$ and $f(x)=-1$. Hence, $f$ attains its minimum value $-1$ on $A$.
